# Trying to implement begin/end with static_cast in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, iterator, static-cast

I'm trying to implement an object to iterate easily an array, without `static_cast` each element separately (I have to do it hundreds of times). It works when I use the classic for loop, but when I attempt to use `begin()`/`data()`/`end()` it fails to compile. Do you know where is the mistake?

If I have these two classes:

```
struct Wrapper
{
   int var1 = 0;
};

struct WrapperBig: public Wrapper
{
   int var2 = 0;
};
```

And this is the object which will cast the pointers:

```
template <class T, int N>
class ArrayCasted final
{
public:
   ArrayCasted(std::array<Wrapper*, N>& p): master(p) {}

   // Works
   int size() const {return static_cast<int>(master.size());}
   inline T* operator[](const int index) {return static_cast<T*>(master[index]);}

   // Fails
   inline T* begin() const noexcept {return static_cast<T**>(master.begin());}
   inline T* end() const noexcept {return static_cast<T**>(master.end());}
   inline T* data() const noexcept {return static_cast<T**>(master.data());}

private:
   std::array<Wrapper*, N>& master;
};
```

When I try to compile in Visual Studio 2019:

```
   Wrapper* w1 = new Wrapper();
   std::array<Wrapper*, 2> values {w1, w1};

   ArrayCasted<WrapperBig, 2> casted {values};

   // Works!
   for (int i=0; i<casted.size(); ++i)
   {
      WrapperBig* current = casted[i];
      current->var2 = -1;
   }

   // Fails :( C2440
   for (WrapperBig* current : casted)
   {
      current->var2 = -1;
   }
```

I tried the same with std::vector, but same problem. I think the mistake is in the `begin`/`data`/`end` functions, but I'm not sure why. I tried multiple things but everything fails.

How can I do this?

Comment: Well for starters, your `begin`/`data`/`end` functions say that they return `T*`.  But their implementations try to return `T**`.  Not the same thing.    I don't know what `Wrapper` is so I cannot speak the validity of your casts

Comment: It's just a simple struct, it's detailed at the begging of the post.

Comment: The loop marked "Works!" actually exhibits undefined behavior. At the bottom, you are doing `Wrapper* w1 = new Wrapper(); static_cast<WrapperBig*>(w1)->var2 = -1;` . But just because you cast a pointer, `Wrapper` object doesn't magically become bigger - it still only has space to store one integer. You scribble over some memory that sits past the `Wrapper` instance.

Comment: Which is the purpose of static_cast then? You always can cast a base class pointer to a derived one, unless I've been doing it wrong during few years and I didn't notice

Comment: @JuanJuezSarmiento: For the downcast to work meaningfully, your pointers need to actually point at `WrapperBig` objects. You normally want to use `dynamic_cast` when doing a cast from base to derived, specifically so it'll only succeed when/if the object it points at is really of the type you're asking for (but for that to work, your classes need at least one `virtual` member).

Comment: You can always cast a base class pointer to a derived class pointer - but you cannot always **use** that derived class pointer. It's only meaningful if the original pointer actually did point to an instance of a derived class.

Comment: @JerryCoffin thanks, but unfortunately, I cannot use dynamic_casts in a realtime thread (it's too cpu intensive), so I must trust it works with static_casts (s)

Comment: @JuanJuezSarmiento: tha's fine, but then it's up to you to assure that it will work, by assuring that what they're pointing at are objects of the derived class.

Comment: Why not simply iterate through `std::array<Wrapper, N>` normally using its own `begin`/`end`/`data` and then individually `static_cast` each `Wrapper*` to the `WrapperBig*` as needed.  What is the added benefit of the complexity `ArrayCasted`?

Comment: @Joe, because I'm trying to keep my code as short and easy to read as possible. It's around 20mb of cpp files. And because I really would like to learn :)

Comment: Unrelated note: it is useless to specify `inline` for methods defined inside the class. *Methods defined inside a class are implicitly `inline`*. That's the case for `size` for example. Make sure you understand what that keyword actually does: to prevent ODR violation (it has no more anything to do with actual inlining).

Comment: Why not a `for_each` function: `for_each_derived<WrapperBig>(values, [](WrapperBig* w){ /*..*/ });`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code has a number of problems.

1. You've gotten your levels of indirection confused a bit.
2. The return from `someArray.begin()` is an iterator, which may be a pointer, but may instead be something else entirely, in which casting it to a pointer will completely fail.
3. If you start with an `array<Wrapper *, 2>`, you probably want the ArrayCasted to be to a `array<WrapperBig *, 2>`.
4. If you're going to use the contents as pointer to `WrapperBig`, you need to assure that what they point at are actually `WrapperBig` objects.

Putting those together we could get something on this order:

```cpp
template <class T, int N>
class ArrayCasted final
{
public:
   ArrayCasted(std::array<Wrapper*, N>& p): master(p) {}

   // Works
   int size() const {return static_cast<int>(master.size());}
   inline T* operator[](const int index) {return static_cast<T*>(master[index]);}

   // These work
   // start from a pointer, cast it to the right kind of pointer:
   inline T* begin() const noexcept {return reinterpret_cast<T*>(master.data());}
   inline T* end() const noexcept {return reinterpret_cast<T*>(master.data() + master.size());}
   inline T* data() const noexcept {return reinterpret_cast<T*>(master.data());}

private:
   std::array<Wrapper*, N>& master;
};

int main() {

   std::array<Wrapper*, 2> values;

   // make sure each actually points at WrapperBig object:
   for (auto & w : values) {
        w = new WrapperBig;
   }

   ArrayCasted<WrapperBig *, 2> casted {values};

   // Doesn't Fail
   int i = -1;
   for (WrapperBig* current : casted)
   {
      current->var2 = i++;
   }

    // auto properly deduces the type too:
    for (auto c : casted) {
        // When you type `c->`, Intellisense knows what comes next has to
        // be either `var1` or `var2`.
        std::cout << c->var2 << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't **pedantically** casting `Base**` to `Derived**` leads to UB?

Comment: Thanks if works flawless. I see my mistakes now

Comment: @Jarod42: Under older versions of the standard, essentially any use of `reinterpret_cast` produced undefined or implementation defined behavior. Under recent versions, I believe the behavior is defined. N4950, [expr.reinterpret.cast]/7 says it's equivalent to: `static_cast<cv T*>(static_cast<cv void*>(v))`. For example, absent a difference in alignment requirements (which shouldn't apply here), you can do a round-trip conversion and be guaranteed you get the original pointer back. I'd have to do a little more looking to be sure about whether dereferencing it gives defined behavior though.